# Misconfigured Redirect URI Uber Android

Tags: android, uber-api

I am implementing custom IMPLICIT login mechanism in ANDROID which as follows,

```
     private SessionConfiguration configuration;
     private LoginManager loginManager;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_login);

     configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
        .setClientId("nHuaAjXVHZbN428PDXnJp4gCL969W8jv")
        .setRedirectUri("com.myproject.ubertest.uberauth")
        .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
        .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS))
        .build();
UberSdk.initialize(configuration);

AccessTokenStorage accessTokenStorage = new AccessTokenManager(SampleLoginActivity.this);
loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenStorage, loginCallback);
loginManager.login(SampleLoginActivity.this);

loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenStorage,
        loginCallback,
        configuration,
        111);

   }

LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
@Override
public void onLoginCancel() {
    // User canceled login
    Log.e("Uber Login Cancelled", "Cancelled");
}

@Override
public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
    // Error occurred during login
    Log.e("Uber Login Error", error.toString());
   }

@Override
public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
    // Successful login!  The AccessToken will have already been saved.
    Log.e("Uber Login Sucess", accessToken.toString());
}

@Override
public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {

}
};
```

Bu i am always getting a alert message saying "An Invalid use of the redirect URI for authentication has been detected from older version of the Uber SDK". Please let me know to resolve the issue.

Note: Also please note that i have configure my redirect URI as com.myproject.ubertest.uberauth://redirect in developer dashboard and Update my key hash too. and i am using this sdk com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your redirect URL in the code to be for example: https://localhost:8181/Callback : setRedirectUri("https://localhost:8181/Callback")
Also, update redirect URL on your developer [dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/). Looks like you are not set up properly your redirect URL to your code. Also if you posted your real ClientId = nHuaAjXVHZbN428PDXnJp4gCL969W8jv - this id does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please specify what is that https://localhost:8181/Callback? Also where and how should i configure them? And i know the ClientId is not the real one.

Comment: From where did you get your ClientId = nHuaAjXVHZbN428PDXnJp4gCL969W8jv?  https://localhost:8181/Callback  is the redirect URL that you need to use in your code - and to set it to your developer aplication. You can use your redirect URL - I just want to make a point that you dont pass redirect URL properly. To clarify "Client Id: nHuaAjXVHZbN428PDXnJp4gCL969W8jv" does not exist. So how did you get it?

Comment: I have changed the client id thinking it could be a confidential. And is it necessary to setup the redirect URL to login with the authentication mechanism with my server since i don't have https one? If yes, can you help me what should be the flow i mean necessary configurations to be done on the server side.

Comment: Thanks - you just need to have same redirect URL on your dashboard with the one you supply to your code. This is all you need to do.

Comment: Apologies for the late response - if you are using the latest version of the Android SDK (v0.9.0) - please check: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#authentication-migration-and-setup-version-08-and-above on how you need to set-up your redirect URL